# Lowest possible CPU/GPU use for screensaver encode for mac (with handbreak or other free / cheap video encoders)

Tags: video, encoding, screensaver

Similar to [What video codec puts the CPU/GPU under the least possible load while decoding?](https://superuser.com/questions/529806/what-video-codec-puts-the-cpu-gpu-under-the-least-possible-load-while-decoding) I want to know what is the best option for a 2014 15 retina mac pro.

I tried MPEG 2 and it won't go as a S/S in quartz (and quicktime won't play it) and I don't know what things a mac pro possibly uses when it is in S/S mode. I know that for regular playback, it should have H.264 decode and everything is fine. But when I use a 720 p H.264 video (~8 minutes 100mb), it runs fine but the fans actually kick in when the s/s is played for some time!

I would love to encode a 1080p video to somehow allow it to play smoothly (~30 fps? 60 fps?) as my S/S. As it stands, any 1080p video set as the S/S will stutter and not play smooth at all. And kick in the fan almost asap.

I tried the baseline setting in handbreak and it produced a workable version, but it still stutters a bit, and the fans still spin up very fast in s/s mode.

Or somehow down sample a 4k video to 1800 and use the workaround to get that res on the screen. Which seems to be a tall task if standard 1080 won't work and 720 strain it after a while...

Maybe I need a stop playing s/s and just darken the screen setting (when it is not plugged in) or darken after x minutes type of dealie.

Comment: In your world, we all know what S/S is.  Clearly we are not all in your world.

Comment: I suppose, from the context here and [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6837195?start=0&tstart=0) (if it is the same user, that is) that he's referring "S/S" as the screensaver.

Comment: It would be screen saver, since the title of the question is screen saver and I'm talking about video compression and 4k videos. Unless this is the 90s, where desktop backgrounds could strain your CPU when a math-co proc is not installed, I don't think a screen shot would be applicable